# Мульти-модельная форма

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Есть 2 класса

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end
```

При создании поста вывожу список тэгов так, в виде чекбоксов:

```
<% Tag.all.each do |tag| %>
  <%= f.check_box :tags, {multiple: true}, tag.id, nil %> <%= tag.title %>
<% end %>
```

На контроллер приходит:

```
"tags"=>["19", "26"]
```

Теперь не понимаю как создать в связующей таблице PostTags соответствующие записи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае не нужна мультимодельная форма. В рельсах из коробки [есть магия](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) для этого. Но нужно использовать не `tags` а `tag_ids`.

```
post = Post.last
post.tag_ids = Tag.ids
```

В результате, к последнему посту будут добавлены, все существующие в БД тэги. В промежуточной таблице записи будут созданы автоматически.

Заодно, для таких чекбоксов тоже есть сахар:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes, :tags_ids, Tag.all, :id, :title %>
```

UPD:

> ```
> <% Tag.all.each do |tag| %>
>   <%= f.check_box :tags, {multiple: true}, tag.id, nil %> <%= tag.title %>
> <% end %>
> ```

У этого цикла есть существенный минус. Т.к. в `unchecked_value` передаётся `nil` - не будут добавляться хиддены, и если сбросить все чекбоксы то параметр просто будет проигнорирован. Если оставить значение по-умолчанию (0), или явно задать например пустую строку, то это значение будет передано вместо каждого невыбранного чекбокса. Второе не страшно, просто неаккуратно. Так что лучше использовать `collection_check_boxes` который добавит только один пустой хидден.

Comment: Я как-то столкнулся с забавным багом, возможно, вы захотите проверить и отразить его у себя в ответе: если не выбрать **ни одного**, то на сервер придёт пустой массив, но по пути до контроллера он превратится в `nil`, из-за чего присвоение `nil` **не сотрёт все ассоциации**, а **проигнорирует изменения**. Это только в Rails 5 починили, он ещё не зарелизился.

Comment: @D-side, хм. Никогда не сталкивался с таким. На первый взгляд выглядит как глюк strong params или проблемы с форм-хэлперами. Есть какие-нибудь ссылки? Я бы изучил вопрос.

Comment: Хе-хе. Да, я тоже так думал. Но нет, это не просто не баг, это **фича** (знаю, знаю), возникшая в качестве фикса какой-то уязвимости в Rails 3.2 (да, так давно!). Тикетов по этому поводу много, [вот довольно яркий](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13766), и вот [тикет о процессе починки](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13420).

Comment: @D-side, насколько я понял, это справедливо для json запросов. Да и `collection_check_boxes` по дефолту добавляет hidden со значением "". Да и `post.tag_ids = nil` вызовет удаление всех записей из промежуточной таблицы.

Comment: Не вызовет, в этом-то и проблема. С пустым массивом вызовет, а с `nil` нет. Цитата: "As a result it will be impossible to clear the collection of property_ids (or generally impossible to clear any other `has_many` collection).". Влияет ли это на `collection_check_boxes`, я не знаю, зависит от того, в каком виде от него параметры прилетают. О чём и говорю, это стоит проверить. У меня впечатление, что это справедливо для обработки `strong_parameters` чего бы там ни было.

Comment: @D-side, у меня удаляется http://joxi.ru/5mdk7o3Cv5NvZr
Рельсы  4.2.5.2, руби 2.2.3

Comment: Интересно, однако. А если сделать `post.update(category_ids: nil)`?

Comment: @D-side, аналогично :) http://joxi.ru/nAyzqQMFX5ZgOr

Comment: Ну, на гитхабе у человека явно не галлюцинации, и явно не такие же, как у меня. У меня два возможных объяснения: либо со времён Rails 4.2.5 это починили, либо это работает в чистых has_many, не HABTM и HMT .-.

Comment: @D-side, хм. А вот сильные параметры подкладывают свинью. http://joxi.ru/DmBXN40uNQ04eA
Т.е. если мидлваре сделает из пустого массива nil - становится трудно запермитить аттрибут.

Comment: М-м! Вот где собака и зарыта, да. Там не `nil`, там **просто убирается ключ**, поэтому и считается, что изменений в это поле вносить не нужно. Вот и разгадка. То есть, это сразу комбинация из `update` и "сильных параметров".

Comment: Но про `collection_check_boxes` я вот что хотел сказать: там не получается пустого массива при штатном использовании. В любом случае будет один элемент - пустая строка. Вроде я не вижу тут проблем с безопасностью. Если штатно отправлять, то отрабатывает как нужно, а если пытаться руками криво запросы слать - просто параметр проигнорируется.

Comment: Да не, проблема изначально не с безопасностью, а скорее с "неожиданным поведением в краеугольном случае". Я себе сломал мозг, пытаясь понять, где рельсы меня надули, и я опасался, что здесь  может произойти похожее явление. Хорошо, что это всё же не так.

Comment: Кстати, [вот](http://joxi.ru/DmBXN40uNQ05NA) небольшой костыль на тему.

Comment: Этот костыль, как я полагаю, и просто скаляры принимает?

Comment: Да. Это очень костыльный костыль. Просто ради эксперимента.

Comment: Странное дело. В контроллере прописал render plain: params[:post].inspect выдает нормальный JSON с помощью консоли делаю
    Post.new({"title"=>"TestTitle", "text"=>"TestText", "category_id"=>"13", "tag_ids"=>["24", "54", "77", "95", "112"]}) после делаю post.save все отлично. Делаю тоже самое в браузере и в связующую таблицу ничего не записывается, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @Павел, а параметры точно пермитятся правильно? `tag_ids` - массив и нужно что-то типа `param.require(:post).permit(:title, :text, :category_id, tag_ids: [])`.

Comment: Да, вы правы ошибка в этом. Вместо tags:[] указал tdg_ids: [], все работает. Спасибо.